# Installing and Using Python Modules in a Docker Container

Tags: python, git, docker, module, installation

I am new to using docker containers.  I have successfully created a new docker container but am now having trouble installing and then using python modules in it.

I entered into the already running container with the following command:

```
$docker exec -it lizzie /bin/bash
```

This worked.  I also managed to install the module of interest to me with the following command:

```
$pip install pysnmp
```

I cloned my git repository, entered the local repo, and attempted to run a script that utilized the module pysnmp.  The following error was returned:

```
ImportError: No module named pysnmp
```

I reinstalled the module to ensure that it had installed correctly; all requirements were already satisfied.  The two folders currently in the docker are a folder called "anaconda-ks.cfg" which I can't enter and the repo.  I feel like this has something to do with the path the module was installed in but I'm not sure where I should be installing it or how to do so.  Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Anaconda, but I think `anaconda-ks.cfg` has to be file, not a directory. Can you add your `Dockerfile` to the question?

Comment: Oh!  Right that is a file.  I'm not familiar with a Dockerfile--where would I find it?

Comment: `Dockerfile` is what defines any Docker image. How did you run your container? Did you use some existing image?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, thanks for your help--I ended up finding a completely different work around to my issue that had nothing to do with docker containers.